# Print from List Python

Tags: python, list

Suppose my list (dictionary?) is given as:

```
a = [{ 'a':'z', 'b':'x', 'c':'w', 'd':'v'}, {{ 'a':'f', 'b':'g', 'c':'h', 'd':'i'}, [...]]
```

I tried to access the elements as follows:

```
print values[0].get(2)
```

and I got None

Comment: That's not a list. What is your exact object?

Comment: This is an invalid set, a set can't contain hashable values.

Comment: Do you mean a list of dictionaries? `a = [{ 'a':'z', 'b':'x', 'c':'w', 'd':'v'}, { 'a':'f', 'b':'g', 'c':'h', 'd':'i'}]`

Comment: Yes. Please, provide meaningful code.

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't have a `2` key.

Comment: And `get` defaults to `None` if it doesn't find anything

Comment: I want to access values such as "z, x, w, v ..."

Comment: Try `values[0].values()[0]`. Or maybe better `values[0].itervalues().next()`

Comment: Interesting that the data you posted, and have now removed, was exactly the same as [this deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636770/dynamic-splitting-of-dictionary-in-python/16636895#16636895)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit unclear, are you looking for this?

```
In [41]: a = [{ 'a':'z', 'b':'x', 'c':'w', 'd':'v'}, { 'a':'f', 'b':'g', 'c':'h', 'd':'i'}]

In [42]: a[0].get('a')
Out[42]: 'z'
```

...or this?

```
In [50]: a[0].values()
Out[50]: ['z', 'w', 'x', 'v']
```

...or using your provided data:

```
In [47]: data = {'style': '-', 'subCat': '-', 'name': 'Eurodollar Futures', 'oi': '9,774,883', 'floor': 'ED', 'url': '/trading/interest-rates/stir/eurodollar_contract_specifications.html', 'clearing': 'ED', 'cpc': 'ED', 'venues': 'Globex Floor ClearPort ', 'cat': '-', 'vol': '2,026,353', 'globex': 'GE', 'group': 'Interest Rate', 'tags': '-', 'cleared': 'Futures', 'id': 1, 'exch': 'CME', 'subGroup': 'Stirs'}

In [48]: data.get('name')
Out[48]: 'Eurodollar Futures'
```

you can also loop over the dictionary:

```
In [52]: for k,v in a[0].iteritems():
   ....:     print k, v
   ....:     
a z
c w
b x
d v
```

Comment: Is there a way to index without using the key name? Suppose there 20 keys and I don't want to type data.get('xxxx') 20 times.

Comment: @dawg you forgot two characters at the end :)

Comment: @FredrikPihl Is it possible to assign values of k and v to another variable in the loop, for exmaple: test1[i] = k test2[i] = v i+=1